# LCDS - Expect List<Long>, get ArrayCollection of Integer

Tags: apache-flex, blazeds, lcds

I have a POJO which declares a collection of `List<Long>`.

We're currently sending an `ArrayCollection` of Number, and it's arriving at the client as an `ArrayCollection`, populated with `Integers`.

Given the issues with Type Erasure & generics I understand how this is happening.  How do I fix it?

Unfortunately because of some internal limitations, the model cannot be changed.  Ie - we can't use a subtype, and we can't implement IExternalizable.

Are there other options for registering custom type converters in LCDS, other than IExternalizable?  Alternatively, are there any annotations we can use that indicate the type to be used for a collection?

Regards

Marty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like https://bugs.adobe.com/jira/browse/BLZ-115. I would try using a custom marshaller, like [this](http://flexblog.faratasystems.com/2010/01/09/custom-type-masrhaller-in-blazeds) one.